# How to refresh widget every second?

Tags: android, widget, refresh, seconds

Look at code below  I need to update this onUpdate method every second, could anybody give some good example, please? Mainly I need to update codes from `CurFreq(context);` to `views.setTextViewText(R.id.text_widget_batt, prefNameBattery+"%");`

```
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
        final int N = appWidgetIds.length;

        for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
            int appWidgetId = appWidgetIds[i];

            Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyActivity.class);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);

            RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget);
            views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.layout_widget, pendingIntent);

            CurFreq(context);
            Temp(context);
            Battery(context);

            SharedPreferences myPrefsInfo = context.getSharedPreferences("myPrefsInfo", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            String prefNameCurFreq = myPrefsInfo.getString(WidgetCurFreq, "");
            String prefNameTemp = myPrefsInfo.getString(WidgetTemp, "");
            String prefNameBattery = myPrefsInfo.getString(WidgetBattery, "");

            views.setTextViewText(R.id.text_widget_freq, prefNameCurFreq);
            views.setTextViewText(R.id.text_widget_temp, prefNameTemp+",0°C");
            views.setTextViewText(R.id.text_widget_batt, prefNameBattery+"%");

            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
        }
}
```

Comment: App widgets are not designed to be updated every second.

Comment: But this is not answer on my question.

Comment: And you will notice that I did not supply it as an answer, but as a comment.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can code a Service and implement a timer , and Update the widget every second accordingly.
Call your method in OnStartCommand(Intent, int, int) Method of Service with in the timer .

Comment: I solved it with Service and Thread in it. But thanks for your advice.